# Command \shadowbox{} (from fancybox package) doesn't work with the \@title command

Tags: titles, fancybox, shadowbox

I'm currently trying to personalize my titlepage with the environment of the same name.

Obviously, I want it to be modular so I only have to use the commands \title{},\author{} and \date{}. I managed to make it work with the "macros" @title, @author and @date BUT I'm trying to put a shadowbox on my title and I've tested it with different kind of text and precisely when I put the macro @title in it, it returns an error.

Here is the LateX code (without anything not useful) :

```
%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE DE BASE %%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[12pt, titlepage]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}

%%%%%%%%%% PACKAGE PRESENTS DANS LE DOC %%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, mathtools, mathrsfs, stmaryrd}
\usepackage{tikz, etoolbox, graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry, enumitem, xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, fancybox, lastpage, float, titling, setspace, titlesec}
\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap}
\usepackage[type={CC}, modifier={by-nc-sa}, version={4.0}, imagemodifier={-eu}]{doclicense}
% Doit être dernier.
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false, hidelinks, colorlinks=false]{hyperref}


% % % % % % %

\title{GREAT TITLE}
\author{MY NAME}
\date{\today}


[...]


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

% Page de titre % 
\begin{titlepage}
    { \doublespacing
    \vspace*{4cm}

    \makeatletter
    \begin{center}
        \shadowbox{test}   % Example of code showing that the shadowbox works as intended
        %\shadowbox{\Huge \@title}   % What I want but doesn't work 
    \end{center}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \begin{center}
        {\large \@author}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
        {\large \@date}
    \end{center}
    \makeatother }
    
    \vfill
    \doclicenseThis
    \vspace{2cm} 
\end{titlepage}
% ---------- %


[...]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't you get an error `Package hyperxmp Error: hyperref must be loaded before hyperxmp. }`?

Comment: If I fix this and the error about missing `\begin{document}`, your code compiles fine, even with the `\shadowbox{\Huge \@title}` line uncommented

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Nope, the error is precisely : "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item." which seems to indicate LateX has no idea whatsoever...

Comment: Is your tex distribution up-to-date?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm currently using Texlive 2023 (the complete version) on VSCode with latex-workshop extension with everything up-to-date.
By the way, i'm on zorin OS 16.3 which is a ubuntu 22.04 distro

Comment: Can you try with this code: https://pastebin.com/tbsDGeyj This works for me with a up-to-date texlive 2023.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I found what was the problem, I've posted an answer below

Comment: Using \\ outside of tables (and similar environment) is usually wrong :) Please update your question with some code which actually reproduces the problem.

Comment: Why are you using shadow box if you are already loading the `tcolorbox` package? Tcolorbox allows to use multiline text.